# Subscribe Facebook page to external app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, webhooks

I have a webapplication where brands have a feed and can post things. I want to make them be able to, whenever they post something on their Facebook page, it becomes posted in the feed of my webapp.

I know I have to use the webhooks and all that. So far, I have tried this:

1. I have created my own app in Facebook.
2. I created a Facebook page (with that same account).
3. I created the webhook.
4. I added my app to my page's subscribed apps.
5. I post something on my page, and it works.

Now, let's say there is Coca Cola, that has a Facebook page.

Is it possible to add my app to Coca Cola page's subcribed apps?

Comment: of course not, you can only subscribe to your own pages

Comment: So, suppose the brand does not have an app. Which would be my solution? Can I request permission, create the app (in the brand account), associate the app with the page and create the webhook, all through APIs and requesting permissions? @luschn

Comment: you need to be admin of their page. not sure what you want to know, to be honest. just test it.

Comment: Do you think there is any other solution to my problem? I just want that, when a brand posts something in their page, it will call my endpoint so I can get the data...

Comment: again, you have to be admin of their page. you can´t just get a webhook from ANY page you don´t even own, that would be weird.

Comment: Yes, I undestand that. But could I get admin permissions through API? Or making the brand giving me permission opening a dialog box and they accept or something like that?

Comment: no, they have to add you to the page manually